# Delete own account ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

For ASP.NET I want that the user is able to remove he's own account. But can't find on the internet a tutorial or such kind how to do it?

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/membership/creating-user-accounts-cs) or [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset)

Comment: @UK_Dev Thanks for the fast reply! The application is based on the second link (create a secure asp.net MVC ..)

Comment: You could implement a controller for this that upon request gathers relevant user details from your SQL tables (or whatever DB service you're using) then just delete from [sometables] where userid = [someid]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. I found the solution it was pretty easy. What is write in my model

````
public ActionResult DeleteUser()
{

            var c = User.Identity.GetUserId(); // get the user id

            UserManager.Delete(UserManager.FindById(c)); // remove the user
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie); // sign out

            /*return RedirectToAction("Login"); // goes to login page*/
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new { area = "" });


        }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Samantha!

There are many ways in doing this. You can assure this functionality by implementing an API responsible with deletion. Read about REST APIs.

I advice you to have a column in your, let's say, user table, call IsEnabled or whatever, and on the request, to update that value with 0. After that, you can have a job ( read about jobs, Quartz or Hangfire libraries), which will run, let's say, once at 30 mins, which will be responsible to trigger a method which delete every data related to those users which are not enabled anymore. I am saying this, because based on how complex is your data model, it can take some time to delete everything about that user and you need, meanwhile, to ensure a feedback to the user that his operation is listen, that's why I propose you this.

But, first of all, read, understand and practicing tutorials about REST APIs, i.e.,  [REST APIs](https://www.restapitutorial.com)
also you can find free good tutorials on Udemy, and not only...

Kind regards,
Stefan.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but I can speculate that it was downvoted because it doesn't remotely answer the question.

Comment: Strictly refereed to the answer, I agree with you, Xander, on the other side, the OP description, didn't make sense, it was too vague. Also, if you look into the solution, we would be never able to provide an answer. Again, when we give up vote or down vote, let's give some input why. I am saying this not because I was down voted, I do not care about numbers, I care about being logical and to improve the Stackoverflow community. Cheers!